# Input.getKeyUp firing continuously on holding key down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the Unity documentation Input.getKeyUp says

> Returns true during the frame the user releases the key identified by name

My script is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveSphere : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 5;

    void Update () {
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
            pos.x -= Time.deltaTime * speed;
            transform.position = pos;
        } else if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.Space)) {
            Debug.Log ("Space key up");
            pos.y += Time.deltaTime * speed;
            transform.position = pos;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)` works as I expected it to so if I hold it down my object continuously moves to the left. However I want my object to "jump" when I press the space bar but I dont want it to continuously go up when the space bar is held which is why I used `Input.GetKeyUp` instead of just `GetKey` however when I hold down the space bar it continuously travels upwards.

How can I make it so when the space bar is held it does nothing but when I release the space bar it travels upward.

Comment: Comment that might have nothing to do with your problem but you should do multiple sequential if statement instead of else if, otherwise you will never go in the "if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.Space)) " as long as the left arrow is pressed (because of the "else").

Comment: @PierreBaret That should only matter if I press both at the same time which is probably a good idea but it still doesn't solve my original problem. Thanks for the recommendation though

Comment: *"when the space bar is held it does nothing"* When the space bar is held down, you want it to cancel out the left arrow keypress which means that `if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow))` should be ignored?

Comment: @Programmer no it doesn't have to cancel that out. Sorry bad wording. It can still move left if I am holding the left arrow I just want it to not travel upwards. I only want it to be able to travel upwards one jump at a time.

Comment: This looks weird. I've tried it with an empty scene and new project and it seems to be working as intended. e.g: Space is triggered only once when I release the space key.
Can you check if there are other scripts -somehow- interfering with this movement script?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why it is behaving in this way, but if I were you I would consider to make each key-checking in a different `if()` clause, instead of the `else if()` you are using. Try to write it like this and see if it works.

And also since

> However I want my object to "jump" when I press the space bar

I would change `GetKeyUp` by `GetKeyDown`

```
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
    pos.x -= Time.deltaTime * speed;
    transform.position = pos;
} 

if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
    Debug.Log ("Space key up");
    pos.y += Time.deltaTime * speed;
    transform.position = pos;
}
```

Comment: I did try this and it still continuously rises as you hold the shift key.

Comment: It continue just rising the GameObject or also spaming the log message: Space key up?

Comment: It continously spams the message as well so it keeps entering the if statement